# Generating py objects via python

Tags: python, object, dynamic-data

I was wondering if there was a rendering library that would take a dictionary object and render a file into py-object syntax. Similar to the `django_extensions` command `dump_script`. I've looked around for an hour but have got no success as of yet. I know it wouldn't take me long to create, but I want to see if there is a supported module for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to generate code from objects? This is possible for some built-in types so if you restrict yourself to them it works, and it's done with the `repr()` function.

```
>>> dictionary = {'foo': 3, u'bar': [6.7]}
>>> str = repr(dictionary)
>>> str
"{'foo': 3, u'bar': [6.7000000000000002]}"
>>> exec("adict = " + str)
>>> adict
{'foo': 3, u'bar': [6.7000000000000002]}
```

In general it's not particularly useful, so you might want to explain your use case.